# AngularJS - Unexpected token {

Tags: angularjs, flask-assets

I am trying to import a service to use it inside my controller, but inside console it is showing this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I am using `Flask-Assets` to minify **javascript** files.

This is my **service** and **controller** files contents:

```
app.service('metaCsrfToken', ['', function () {
    this.get_token = function(){

        var csrf_token = angular.element('meta[name=csrf_token]')

        return csrf_token[0].content

    }

}]);

import { metaCsrfToken } from '../services/owasp'

app.controller('call-center.controller', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$log', '$compile', '$timeout', '$interval', 'toastr', '$filter', 'metaCsrfToken',

    function($scope, $http, $window, $log, $compile, $timeout, $interval, toastr, $filter, metaCsrfToken){

        // .........

        console.log(metaCsrfToken.get_token())

}]);
```

Full error path:

```
_app_scripts.js?93a3d221:100 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

100 import{metaCsrfToken}from'../services/owasp'
101 app.controller('call-center.controller',['$scope','$http','$window','$log','$compile','$timeout','$interval','toastr','$filter','metaCsrfToken',function($scope,$http,$window,$log,$compile,$timeout,$interval,toastr,$filter,metaCsrfToken){$scope.numberInput
102 console.log(metaCsrfToken.get_token())}]);
```

Comment: Can you share your full stack trace including line numbers?

Comment: Do you mean minified javascript file content? its too long ?

Comment: No I mean your error stack trace. This should be shown in your console and shows exactly which line triggers the error. Right now you have only shared the error message, not the full stack trace.

Comment: Question updated!

Comment: Thank you for updating. Just to clarify: does this error also happen when the code is not minified?

Comment: @Mathyn, thank you too for your interest, yes it happens!!

Comment: @Mathyn, really strange! i am stucking on this problem about an hour and a half!!

Comment: Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: @Mathyn, Google Chrome. Also all my base template is based on Flask-Bootstrap extension blocks https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#templates

Comment: I am not sure what is going wrong here. However I did find [this](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) tool which highlights the `import` statement as problematic. However other similar tools do not do this.

Comment: @Mathyn, but why import is wrong in AngularJS? is it just for Angular7?

Answer (score 0):

So finally i resolved the problem, just by creating a service and inject it into controller:

```
app.service('csrfToken', function csrfTokenFactory() {
    this.get_token = function(){

        var csrf_token = angular.element('meta[name=csrf_token]')

        return csrf_token[0].content

    }
});

app.controller('call-center.controller', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$log', '$compile', '$timeout', '$interval', 'toastr', '$filter', 'csrfToken',

    function($scope, $http, $window, $log, $compile, $timeout, $interval, toastr, $filter, csrfToken){

        // ......

        console.log(csrfToken.get_token())

}]);
```

I don't know why **import** always gives that error!!!